# Windsor Generic Decorator

Tags: c#, generics, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm trying to get a generic decorator around several non-generic command handlers. Is this possible without registering each command handler individually?

Current Windsor command handler registration (works):

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(namespaceName)
    .BasedOn(typeof(IDomainCommandHandler<>))
    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

Simple decorator:

```
public class Decorator<T> : IDomainCommandHandler<T> where T : IDomainCommand
{
    private readonly IDomainCommandHandler<T> _decoratedCommandHandler;

    public Decorator(IDomainCommandHandler<T> decoratedCommandHandler)
    {
        _decoratedCommandHandler = decoratedCommandHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(T command)
    {
        _decoratedCommandHandler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

Simple command/handler:

```
public class MyCommand : IDomainCommand
{

}

public class MyCommandHandler : IDomainCommandHandler<MyCommand>
{
    public void Handle(MyCommand command)
    {
    }
}
```

I tried the following registration, but the decorator is not applied.

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDomainCommandHandler<>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(Decorator<>))
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

Suggestions?

EDIT:
One additional restriction I forgot to mention originally is that some of these command handlers are used by two different applications. One needs the decorator, the other does not.

Comment: Do you get "Dependency cycle has been detected when trying to resolve component..."?

Comment: I get no error. The decorator is simply not applied.

Comment: @agartee how do you resolve a command handler?

Comment: We're using something very similar to Udi Dahan's domain event processor: http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting "Dependency cycle has been detected when trying to resolve component...", right? That is because ctor of the decorator contains IDomainCommandHandler<T>

```
public Decorator(IDomainCommandHandler<T> decoratedCommandHandler)
```

and when you try to resolve IDomainCommandHandler <T> inside the Decorator it blows up.

The resolution chain here is as follows :

1. Give me IDomainCommandHandler

   ```
   //MyCommand type could be provided through a TypeFactoryComponentSelector     
   var myDecoratedCommandHandler = container.Resolve<IDomainCommandHandler<MyCommand>>();
   ```
2. Castle resolves the Decorator<> but then it goes to resolve its own dependency

   ```
   IDomainCommandHandler<T> decoratedCommandHandler
   ```

And because you already provided T, which in this case is MyCommand, Castle goes to resolve Decorator once again and when it does it twice - it gives up. The only registration for IDomainCommandHandler is Decorator<T>. This kind of problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087489/registering-open-generic-decorators-for-typed-implementations-in-castle-windsor).

You can achive "decorator" like properties with [DynamicProxy](http://kozmic.net/dynamic-proxy-tutorial/).

The decorator pattern is usually applied when you want to extend an implementation. Is that the case? Can you give an example of possible augmentation of your DomainCommandHandlers? Are you trying to implement Cross Cutting Concerns?

The only possible answer which sticks to your style is implementing [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) with ITypedFactoryComponentSelector or FactoryMethod and use the resolution stack. Then you can traverse recursively the resolution stack of the container and return MyDomainCommandler if you have Decorator in the stack. This looks like a hook to the resolve chain which says "Now I see that you are already resolving the Decorators dependencies, so please resolve not a Decorator again."

Comment: "Can you give an example". Well, what do think about adding: permission based security, row based security, field validation, business rule validation, audit trailing, transaction handling, deadlock retying, profiling.. Do I need to go on? I usually apply most of these cross-cutting concerns to my command handlers in the applications I write.

Comment: All of these are actual and real requirements but implementing them as decorators of your domain services/commands in one place looks like an overuse of the pattern. Just my opinion. Did you see [Sharp Architecture](docs.sharparchitecture.net/en/latest/) - they have good ideas. You can even take a look at the MVC pipeline - You have separate places in the pipe for Autho&Authe, Model validation, Model Binding... etc. Did you try Dynamic Proxy? I find it good for cross cutting concerns.

Comment: I'll have a look, but right now my needs are simple. Heading straight for something like PostSharp seems extreme. Windsor interceptors might make more sense, and I shouldn't have registration issues if setting them via attributes, but now I have to update all of my commands and its one more thing to remember when new commands are defined. Interceptors and PostSharps implementation are essentially decorators.

Comment: I found another question where the answer suggests using an ISubDependencyResolver here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637216/how-can-i-register-a-generic-decorator-using-castle-windsor