# How to auto-register (by convention) generic decorator in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am new to Castle Windsor and I was wondering if someone could help me with registering the following components in a generic way so all my commands get auto-registered. And also how to add a decorator.

EDIT: The following seems to work but i am stuck on how to configure a decorator.

```
        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        container
            .Register(
                Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
                    .BasedOn(typeof(ICommand))
                    .LifestyleTransient());

public interface ICommand
{
}

public interface ICommandArgs
{
}

public interface ICommand<TArgs> : ICommand where TArgs : ICommandArgs
{
    void Execute(TArgs args);
}

public class ChangePasswordArgs : ICommandArgs
{
    public ChangePasswordArgs()
    {
    }
}

public class ChangePasswordCommand : ICommand<ChangePasswordArgs>
{
    public void Execute(ChangePasswordArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[CHANGING PASSWORD]");
    }
}
 public class TransactionCommand<TArgs> where TArgs : ICommandArgs
{
    private readonly ICommand<TArgs> innerCommand;

    public TransactionCommand(ICommand<TArgs> innerCommand)
    {
        this.innerCommand = innerCommand;
    }

    public void Execute(TArgs args)
    {
        this.innerCommand.Execute(args);
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is where i am currently at but the decorator is not being resolved correctly:

```
       container.Register(
            Component.For(typeof(ICommand<>))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(TransactionalCommand<>))
                    .LifestyleTransient(),
            Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
                .BasedOn(typeof(ICommand<>))
                    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                        .LifestyleTransient()
        );
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read http://mikehadlow.blogspot.in/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-4-how-to.html ?

Comment: yes i did but it does not cover auto-registration

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=castle%20windsor%20decorator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=castle%20windsor%20by%20convention) are lists of all the topics regarding Castle, auto-registration(by convention) and decorators. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087489/registering-open-generic-decorators-for-typed-implementations-in-castle-windsor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093818/is-there-a-way-to-explicitly-register-open-generic-decorators-with-castle-windso) are good examples. It will be more productive for you if you try to search for the problem first and read around because it is answered long ago already.
A good book on IoC in .NET with Castle is [this one](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) by Mark Seeman. The book shows many examples with castle. You can check out his blog too.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but please consider creating some examples within your answer.  Link-only answers are strongly discouraged since the links may change or get removed.